# discum reads embed and clicks

Tags: python, discord, discum

```
def start_bot(token , channelID , user_id ):
   bot = discum.Client(token=token)
   @bot.gateway.command
   def anigame2(resp):
        if resp.event.message or resp.event.message_updated:
            m = resp.parsed.auto()
            try:
                if m['author']['id'] == '571027211407196161':
                    if len(m["components"]) > 0:
                        embeds = m['embeds'][0]
                        if len(embeds) > 0:
                            target_str = "Challenging Area"
                            if target_str in embeds.get('title', ''):
                                buts = Buttoner(m['components'])
                         
                                bot.click(
                                      m["author"]["id"],
                                      channelID=m["channel_id"],
                                      guildID=m.get('guild_id'),
                                      messageID=m["id"],
                                      messageFlags=m["flags"],
                                      data=buts.getButton(row=0, column=0)
                                  )
            except:
                pass 

def start_bots():
    tokens = open("tokens.txt", 'r').readlines()
    channels = open("channels.txt", 'r').readlines()
    users = open("users.txt", 'r').readlines()

    if len(tokens) != len(channels) or len(tokens) != len(users):
        print("Number of tokens, channels, and users should be the same.")
        return
    threads = []  # Create a list to hold all threads

    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        token = tokens[i].strip()
        channelID = channels[i].strip()
        user_id = users[i].st`your text`rip()
    
        t = threading.Thread(target=start_bot, args=(token, channelID, user_id))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)  # Add the thread to the list
    
# Join all the threads
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   while True:
   start_bots()
```

#i want to make a auto click button for discord, also i running multiple tokens at once with different channelids for more info i am trying to auto farm a discord bot called anigame please help and thank you very much